# Making a div to move up and down on clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div>Content to be displayed</div>
```

Now on clicking h1 the whole and  should move upwards and again  on clicking h1 both should come down.How can i achieve this.I used jquery toggle function to move div up and down but I also want h1 to move upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it'd be easiest to animate a container element.

You could use jQuery to wrap them.

```
var container = $('h1, div').wrapAll('<div />').parent();
```

Then you would give that container `display: relative`. You could do it with an external stylesheet (recommended), or with jQuery.

```
container.css('position', 'relative');
```

Then you could attack a click handler to that `container`.

```
container.toggle(
function() {
   $(this).animate({ top: '-=20px' }, 500);
},
function() {
   $(this).animate({ top: '+=20px' }, 500);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/hGSZS/).

Answer (score 1):

What both elements in a div and make that div move up and down.

```
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <div>Content to be displayed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Considering the answer you marked as correct is prety much the same thing the error was probably on your side. Good thing you've got it fixed though!